# How to connect with vpnc and wifi at the same time?

Tags: vpn, vpnc

everyone,

I just came into a problem. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 for my laptop. In order to connect with the Cisco vpn in my department, I installed vpnc, network-manager-vpnc, and network-manager-vpnc-gnome. Now, I can successfully connect with the vpn after authentication. However, as long as I connect with the vpn, I cannot connect with the wifi, namely, I cannot open any web page. Does anyone know what I should do next?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Connected over the vpn to your office means your office controls the connection to the internet. So you ask the network manager at your office access to internet.

Comment: In fact, I have been authorized to connect the vpn with my ID and password. The people from the IT office tell me that there maybe something wrong with the settings on my computer.   Do you have any idea about what it could be? Thanks.

Comment: As was already suggested in the Answer below, have a loot at your proxy settings. When you connect to your home wifi, the proxy settings are set automatically through DHCP. It looks like when you connect thru VPN, your machine is just given an IP address. You will have to check with your network admin what the settings should be and set them manually. This page can help: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-proxy.html

Comment: Thanks very much. Now, I know the problem, I cannot connect with the vpnc and the wifi at the same time through the network configuration on the desktop, even the indicator on the panel shows that I have connected with the vpnc successfully. However, I can make it through the terminal. I haven't figured out why this would happen...

Answer (score 0):

try looking at proxychains its a application that routes all the traffic to a specific proxy. since when you connect to the vpn the service routes the whole traffic thru it, maybe browser started within proxychain will not follow the vpn tunnel. this is not really a answer but is a direction to be looking for to solve your problem. proxychains